# The image Size validation is not working

Tags: php

Hello I have a validation check for my form which is checking the images existing, count and

size in a IF condition but in here the image size validation is not working.

In my code I have defined that users can only upload up to 500 KB six images size but here I am

unable to upload six images which total all of them are only 340 KB.

Here is the Code:

```
        $maxsize = '500000'; //Bytes    
        $errors = array();

    if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'][0])) 

    {
    $errors[] = 'You have not selected any image for uplaod field'; 
    }
    elseif ($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size'] > $maxsize )

    {
    $errors[] = 'All six images must be less than 500 KB size'; 
    }

   else 
    {

    if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']) !== 6)
        $errors[] = "-Your Only Allowed Six Images";


    $whitelist = array("jpg","png","JPG","PNG");

    foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) 
    {
        if ($file) 
        { 

            $temp = explode('.', $file);

            if (!in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 

            {
                $errors[] = "-All images must be JPG or PNG<br>";
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try echo this value "$_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size']" & then print the result of this condition also "($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size'] > $maxsize )"

Comment: @RohitBatra: I print but i have not got any value here is print code:  print  $_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size'];

Comment: try print_r($_FILES) & then see in that if the key exists or not?

Comment: @RohitBatra: I got this: Array ( [Upload_Property_Images] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 1.jpg [1] => 2.jpg [2] => 3.jpg [3] => 4.jpg [4] => 5.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg [3] => image/jpeg [4] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php66C4.tmp [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php66C5.tmp [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\php66C6.tmp [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\php66C7.tmp [4] => C:\xampp\tmp\php66C8.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 36349 [1] => 37222 [2] => 38792 [3] => 35873 [4] =>

Comment: @RohitBatra: What I should do now ?

Comment: change the condition to elseif(array_sum($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size']) > $maxsize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Code Snippet.

```
    $maxsize = '500000'; //Bytes    
    $errors = array();

if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'][0])) 

{
$errors[] = 'You have not selected any image for uplaod field'; 
}
elseif (array_sum($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['size']) > $maxsize )

{
$errors[] = 'All six images must be less than 500 KB size'; 
}

else 
{

if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']) !== 6)
    $errors[] = "-Your Only Allowed Six Images";


$whitelist = array("jpg","png","JPG","PNG");

foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) 
{
    if ($file) 
    { 

        $temp = explode('.', $file);

        if (!in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 

        {
            $errors[] = "-All images must be JPG or PNG<br>";
            break;

        }
    }
}
}
```